# QGraphicsScene to HTML?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsscene

Using Qt, I am working on a tool that displays items in a `QGraphicsScene`. Items are both polygons and `QGraphicsTextItems`. The latter can contain hyperlinks.

*Problem*: I am trying to export the diagrams and I would like to keep the hyperlinks active.

Using `QImage` renderers produce nice PNG but (obviously) no hyperlinks.
`QSvgRenderer` produce SVG that also do not embed the hyperlinks.

`QPrinter` allows to generate PDF that do the job (more or less) - hyperlinks *are* clickable, and that is what I need in principle. Except that I want to publish the diagram on the web, so PDF is not really an option for me.

I could not find any way render the `QGraphicsScene` in an HTML form. Did I miss something?  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

**EDIT**

A code example:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)

item = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem()
item.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
item.setHtml('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Hello</a>')
item.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse)

scene.addItem(item)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

This example displays a scene with a clickable hyperlink (that opens the link with the default system application). In my application the scene also contains some graphical item but I think this is sufficient to get the idea: I would like to have this scene rendered (or printed or exported) in HTML so that the links would remain clickable.

The following code does the export to PDF:

```
pdf_printer = QPrinter()
pdf_printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
pdf_printer.setPaperSize(rect.size().toSize(), QPrinter.Point)
pdf_printer.setFullPage(True)
pdf_printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
pdf_painter = QPainter()
pdf_painter.begin(pdf_printer)
scene.render(pdf_painter, source=rect)
pdf_painter.end()
```

And the resulting PDF does contains the active hyperlinks - this is what makes me thinks that all the mechanics is there. I just cannot find a way to export in HTML instead of PDF.

Comment: Please post a simplified version of your code.

Comment: What about http://www.qtforum.org/article/3034/qprinter-html.html

Comment: Thanks. But I fear it does not help. It only addresses the (manual) conversion of a text to HTML - which is straightforward. Here I have complete diagrams made of `QPainterPath` and nested text (with hyperlinks). I can eventually end up parsing the scene items and generate the HTML tags manually, but I am looking for a more automated solution - if that exists.